# ibuffer not displaying "*mu4e-main*" buffer

Tags: mu4e, ibuffer

Upon opening mu4e, I expect the `*mu4e-main*` buffer to appear in the list generated by `M-x ibuffer`. However, even after typing `/ /`, i.e., `M-x ibuffer-filter-disable`, the `*mu4e-main*` buffer is not in the list.

Is there some property of buffers that ibuffer always excludes by default? I was unable to find any such setting.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the precise name of the buffer in question is `*mu4e-main*`, with a space in front, making it an invisible buffer.

To display invisible buffers in the ibuffer listing, `C-u g` will refresh the list, with the prefix argument toggling invisible buffers. See the documentation of `ibuffer-update` for more information.